# mappingMongoConverter.setMapKeyDotReplacement doesnt seem to have any effects

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to convert a custom object that contains a map containing dotted key string value using the latest 1.7.2 spring mongodb.

Setting a dot replacement doesnt seem to do the job. Here's my code :

```
class FakeUser {
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    void addValue(String key, String value) {
        this.map.put(key, value);
    }
}

FakeUser fakeUser = new FakeUser();
fakeUser.addValue("test.dot.for.key", "test.dot.for.value");
this.mappingMongoConverter.setMapKeyDotReplacement(":");
Object convertedObject = this.mappingMongoConverter.convertToMongoType(fakeUser);
System.out.println("convertedObject: " + convertedObject.getClass() + ":" + convertedObject);
```

And the output:

`convertedObject: class com.mongodb.BasicDBObject:{ "map" : { "test.dot.for.key" : "test.dot.for.value"}}`

And i also tried:

```
class FakeUser {
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    void addValue(String key, String value) {
        this.map.put(key, value);
    }
}

FakeUser fakeUser = new FakeUser();
fakeUser.addValue("test.dot.for.key", "test.dot.for.value");
this.mappingMongoConverter.setMapKeyDotReplacement(":");
BasicDBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject();
this.mappingMongoConverter.write(fakeUser, dbo);
System.out.println("dbo: " + ":" + dbo.toMap());
```

And with the output of `dbo: :{_class=app.security.MyClass$1FakeUser, map={ "test.dot.for.key" : "test.dot.for.value"}}`

I was expecting "test.dot.for.key" to become "test:dot:for:key", so what did i do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You need make adjustments to the converter in your SpringMongoDBConfig (which should extend AbstractMongoConfiguration) config files, rather than in the class you're trying to serialize/deserialze.  If you're using annotation driven settings, you can use a custom bean to set the converter like so:

```
@Bean
@Override
public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter() throws Exception
{
    DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory());
    MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, mongoMappingContext());
    converter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());
    //mongo won't accept key values with dots(.) in them, so configure it to store them as :
    converter.setMapKeyDotReplacement("\\:");

    return converter;
}
```

Once the converter is setup, it will handle both serialization and deserialization for you automagically.

If you really want to do the conversion in-line (not recommended), you can just use a string replace function to re-write the string like so:

```
class FakeUser 
{
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    void addValue(String key, String value) {
        key = key.replace(".",":");
        this.map.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Although, if you do it inline you'll likely have issues deserializing when you get it back out of mongo.